# Probability that $\frac{x+y}{xy}$ is infinite decimal

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

For natural numbers $x$ and $y$, if both are smaller or equal to $6$,
what's the probability that $\frac{x+y}{xy}$ is infinite decimal?

I calculated it, and I got $18/36=1/2$, but the solution of the book is $17/36$. Am I wrong or the book? Or is there any other explanation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How you calculated it?

Comment: I literally calculated all the possible cases......

Comment: how many sums are there ? how many products ?

Comment: Hint: the fraction will terminate iff the prime factorization of the denominator of that fraction contains no primes other than 2 or 5.

Comment: When $x=y$ then infinite decimal occurs when $x = 3$ and when $x = 6$. When $x \neq y$ then if $(x+y)/xy$ is infinite decimal then exchange the values of $x$ and $y$, the result will still be infinite decimal. So, the total pairs of $x$ an $y$ out of $36$, which satisfy the condition must be even. So, the solution of the book seems to me to be incorrect. Will add this as answer only if this logic is correct.

Comment: I counted 18 too, so the solution might be wrong?

Comment: umm roddy i can't get your point... there can be 36 combinations of (x,y), and the original problem is using two different dices X and Y.

Comment: oh thank you everybody. now I am sure that the solution of the book is wrong.

Comment: @DhruvKohli-expiTTp1z0 . You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr I think you are correct.

However, if you want an efficient way to solve this, here is one.

The only possible prime factors of the denominator are $2,3$ and $5$, since it is the product of two numbers which are at most $6$. The only one of these that can cause an infinite decimal is $3$. So you get an infinite decimal if and only if one of the following holds:

- exactly one of $x$ and $y$ is divisible by $3$
- $x=y=3$
- $x=y=6$

The case $x=3,y=6$ (or the other way around) shouldn't be counted as it gives $\frac{x+y}{xy}=0.5$.

Now you just need to work out the probabilities of the three options, and add.